# content is not centered even with margins set correctly

Tags: css, ssi

i'm having this problem related to my content not centering....i have read everything and have done everything my logic is telling me but i see no change or result...
-it should also be noted that this problem started to happen when i started to use the  at the top of every page but maybe i'm not making space for it properly like i should so it has just messed everything else up....

**edit** i guess what i'm trying to do is create a space about 115px at the top of every page on my website so can i use SSI to insert my header which includes my menu, logo and some social links, maybe i'm going about this wrong?

here is my css:

```
body{
font-family: sans-serif, times, serif;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
padding-top:10px;
width:100%;
}

#centered{
width:900px;
height:auto;
margin:0px auto;
}
#menu{
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
.content{
background:none;
position:absolute;
margin:0px auto;
height:auto;
top:115px;
left:0px;
}
#feature img{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px solid white;
    border-radius:2px;
}

div.centercolumn{
position:relative;
left:8px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
margin:8px;
}

p.mission,.impact{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.2em;
    max-width:900px;
    clear:both;
}

p.mission{
    padding-top:10px;
}

#programs{
    position:relative;
    left:2px;
    top:0px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

    .spread{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px 12px

}

    span{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
}
```

then my html:

```
<body>
<div id="centered">
<div id="menu">
<!--#include virtual="/menus/menu.html" -->
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="feature">
        <img id="imagefeature" src="http://www.unifiedforuganda.com/resources/test%20homepage.jpg" alt="fall 2013 tour" />
    </div>
    <div class="centercolumn" id="programs">
        <p class="impact">Our Impact</p>
        <a href="#" class="imglink spread" id="mentorship" alt="Mentorship Program"><span></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="imglink spread" id="sponsorship" alt="Sponsorship Program"><span></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="imglink spread" id="scholarship" alt="Scholarship Program"><span></span></a>
        <p class="mission">Our Mission</p>
        <p class="promotiontext">We emotionally and financially support the most destitute children of northern Uganda through scholarship and mentorship.<br>U4U is student led organization that is registered as an official 501(c)3.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any display:block; or display:inline-block; in your css

Comment: @Keith is correct. You need to assign `display: block` to your centered `div`

Comment: Note that a `<div>` by default is a block-level element; `display:block` should not be necessary.

Comment: hey      ok....i see that....doesn't seem to have any effect...here is the updated code on the web: http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/homepage.html

Comment: maybe i should ask another question: basically i want to create a free space above the main content of the page so that when i insert using SSI there is space for it above the main content....does that make sense?

Comment: I haven't used SSI in a long time, but it should send the "compiled" html (this markup with the contents of the included file injected where appropriate) to the browser.  Unless you have absolute positioning going on, there should be no reason to add any padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your CSS for centering the `#centered` element is in fact correct! So don't worry, you were on the right track there.

The problem actually lies with the content of the `#centered` element - the styling of the `.content` element. It is given `position:absolute`, which means it gets taken out of the layout, and as such the positioning of `#centered` has no effect over it (since `#centered` does no have `position:relative`).

There are two ways to fix this that I can see right now: First, you could add `position:relative` to the definition for `#centered`, so your CSS looks like this:

```
#centered {
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

This will cause your absolutely-positioned `.content` to be positioned relative to the `#centered` element. Alternatively (and the approach I prefer), you can remove the absolute positioning on `.content`, since it doesn't seem to needed to be there. With removal of some other attributes rendered unnecessary and adding of a margin instead, it would look like this:

```
.content {
    margin-top:115px;
    background:none;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4ctrh/1/) of the second solution. If you expand the viewport, you'll see that the elements are now centered in the screen. Note that if the content you're inserting server-side won't be absolutely positioned (or rather, will be in the flow of the document), the `margin-top:115px` isn't even necessary, since any content you add will simply push the `.content` element downwards as needed.

If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: hey      thanks that worked! i should have seen that....i just starting learning CSS last week and i was afraid it was something out of my scope because of the SSI but i should have definitely known that...thanks!!!

Comment: Great, glad I could help out! CSS is really fun to use, but there are a lot of little rules to memorize. The space at the top (above the banner, I think?) is either due to `top:115px` or `margin-top:115px` on `.content` (depending on which route you went down). I left the space there since that's how your CSS was written before, but if you don't want it anymore, you can just delete that particular style (in the case of `top:115px`, replace with `top:0`).

Comment: hey   yep i got that thanks, i was reading the "meat" of you answer and then went back and read the details and picked that up, thanks a ton!